# python mysqldb inserting NULL using a prepared statement

Tags: python, insert, null, prepared-statement, mysql-python

I'm having issues with python when I try to insert `NULL` into a field using a prepared mysqldb statement.  The problem is that python doesn't like `NULL` without quotes and then MySQL doesn't like `'NULL'` with quotes; so I'm trying to find a way to insert `NULL` that both, python and MySQL, will allow.  Here is my scenario:

```
    sqlFailInsert = """INSERT INTO efix_headers ( PathID ) VALUES ( %s );"""
    //then later in my code
    failcur = self.db.query( self.sqlFailInsert, ( pathID if pathID else NULL ) )
```

This generates a python error of: `global name 'NULL' is not defined` but when I use: `pathID if pathID else 'NULL'` MySQL treats it as a string (by the way, pathID field is an integer field) and enters `0` for the value (as it should if you were entering a string into an int field).

So, my questions is, how can I insert `NULL` into the int field using a prepared statement and not violate python rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `None` instead of `NULL`

```
sqlFailInsert = """INSERT INTO efix_headers ( PathID ) VALUES ( %s );"""
//then later in my code
failcur = self.db.query( self.sqlFailInsert, ( pathID if pathID else None ) )
```

Comment: And MySQL will evaluate 'None' to NULL automatically?

Comment: Yes. "SQL NULL values are represented by the Python None singleton on input and output". More information at: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/